# Проблемы с сертификатами OpenServer

Tags: ssl, composer, openserver

Использую OpenServer 5.6 (PHP 7.1x64)

При попытке создать новый Laravel-проект с помощью Композера командой `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog` вижу в командной строке следующее:

> Installing laravel/laravel (v5.6.21)
>     - Installing laravel/laravel (v5.6.21): Downloading (failed) Downloading (failed) Downloading (failed)    Failed to download
>   laravel/laravel from dist: The
>   "https://api.github.com/repos/laravel/laravel/zipball/3f92cf66f53b3b53467497acc0d2a00cbd7b65f0"
>   file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1.
>   OpenSSL Error messages: 
> error:14090086:SSL
>   routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
>  Failed
>   to enable crypto
>  failed to open stream: operation failed
>       Now trying to download from source
>     - Installing laravel/laravel (v5.6.21): Cloning 3f92cf66f5 from cache 
>   
> Created project in blog

Так по всем зависимостям. 
Раньше все работало нормально!

PHP-7.1-x64.ini:

```
[curl]
curl.cainfo = "%sprogdir%/modules/php/%phpdriver%/cacert.pem"

[openssl]
openssl.cafile="%spr
```

`git config --global http.sslVerify false` результата не принес

В чем может быть дело, какие варианты для исправляения могут быть? Заранее спасибо

Comment: Раньше работало — это насколько раньше?

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло отключение проверки защищенных соединений в моем KIS.